# Update a sub object on a parent object in one query

Tags: mongodb

Hello I have an array of clients on an image object, like this:

```
{
        id: 1,
        path: "2013-02/12", 
        clients:
        [
            {
                    id: 321,
                    alias: "Test: audienceDev",
            }
        ],
},
```

The client object is updated elsewhere, I need to update the client object on this image object.

I have tried:

```
            $this->mongoDB->Image->update(
                array('clients.id' => (int) $document->id),
                array('$set' => array('client' => $document)),
                array('multiple' => true)
            );
```

and

```
            $this->mongoDB->Image->update(
                array('clients[].id' => (int) $document->id),
                array('$set' => array('client' => $document)),
                array('multiple' => true)
            );
```

Neither updates the client object on the image object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have an array of clients, so to update every client object, you should do this:

```
$this->mongoDB->Image->update(
  array('clients.id' => (int) $document->id),
  array('$set' => array('clients.$' => $document)),
  array('multiple' => true)
);
```

This will find all the clients with that '$document->id' and updates every client (.$) of the 'clients' array.

Answer (score 0):

```
array('$set' => array('client' => $document))
```

What is the *client* field? you are haven't it.

For update a list of objects you have to replace the whole entire list. Or push new entry and pull the old. Because when you are try to find documents by *clients.id* criteria, you got list of documents, not *clients* list only.
Also, you can write a js-function for updates like you need. And store it in mongodb.